# How do I factor trinomials of the format $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Take, for example, the polynomial $15x^2 + 5xy - 12y^2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have is a *homogeneous* polynomial of degree $2$ in $x$ and $y$ (homogeneous means that the total degree is the same in each monomial).

Divide through by $y^2$, and set $Z=\frac{x}{y}$. (This is called "de-homogeneization"). This will give you the one-variable degree $2$ polynomials
$$aZ^2 + bZ + c.$$
If you know how to factor these (which is not hard), then after factoring
$$aZ^2 + bZ + c = (rZ+s)(tZ+u)$$
you can multiply through by $y^2$ by multiplying one $y$ in each factor on the right hand side, to get back to the homogeneous form ("homogeneization"):
$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 = (rx+sy)(tx+uy).$$
So it all comes down to factoring degree $2$ *polynomials*.

Answer (score 2):

D'you know how to factor $15x^2+5x-12$? Can you see how to go from there to what you want?

Comment: After reading Arturo's answer, what you asked made more sense; I was thinking of the steps I took to factor ax^2 + bx + c rather than the logic behind what I did in factoring that. :)

Answer (score 2):

For degree $2$ polynomials we can use the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula). This will solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

For general $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,$ with integers $a,b,c,$ we calculate the discriminant $$ \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c.  $$
If $b^2 - 4 a c$ is nonnegative and a perfect square, such as $0,1,4,9,16, \ldots,$ then the form can be factored, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real, with $a \ne 0$, and we are factoring over the reals.

We can write our polynomial as 
$$\frac{1}{4a}\left(4a^2x^2+4abxy+4ac\right).$$
Complete the square. We get
$$\frac{1}{4a}\left((2ax+by)^2-(b^2-4ac)y^2\right).$$
If we are trying to factor over the *reals*, and $b^2-4ac$ is negative, there will be no factorization. But if $b^2-4ac \ge 0$, then we can factor as 
$$\frac{1}{4a}\left(\left(2ax+\left(b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\right)y\right)\left(2ax+\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\right)y\right)\right).$$
If we wish, we can absorb $\frac{1}{4a}$ in various ways into the "main" factors.

For your particular example, the factorization is 
$$\frac{1}{60}\left(30x+(5-\sqrt{745})y\right)\left(30x+(5+\sqrt{745})y\right).$$

Comment: Ok so I wanted to ask how to factor $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ explicitly snd you did it here but I really do not see the intuition to pulling out $\frac{1}{4a}$ could you go over how you factor that thing plz

Answer (score 0):

If you're curious, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149825/28900) for comparison. Note that the factorizations won't necessarily be integer factorizations. However, the methods for factoring $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ are basically the same as those for factoring $ax^2+bx+c$, but with one extra step at the end.