# How to factor the polynomial $5x^2 - 2x - 10$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

I want to factor this polynomial without using the quadratic formula. So, as the first step I multiply coefficient of $x^2$ with $-10$. The product obtained is $-50$. However, there are no two factors of $-50$ that add up to $-2$ and give the product as $-50$. So, it becomes evident that the polynomial would be difficult to factor by splitting the middle term. So, according to my level of understanding, the next method I would try is by expressing the polynomial as the difference of two squares and use the identity $a^2 - b^2 = (a + b) (a - b)$. Here is my first try at expressing it as the difference of two squares:

$$5x^2 - 2x - 10$$
$$= 4x^2 - 4x + 1 + x^2 + 2x - 11 $$
$$= (2x - 1)^2 + x^2 + 2x - 11$$

I am not able to solve beyond this. So, I tried the same method but with different manipulation of the polynomial:

$$5x^2 - 2x - 10$$
$$= 9x^2 - 6x + 1 - 4x^2 + 4x - 11$$
$$= (3x - 1)^2 - 4x^2 + 4x - 11$$

Again, I can't go beyond this. So, I want to know whether I am using the wrong method or am I just not able to decide the next manipulation of the polynomial?

Comment: Would it help you to know that this polynomial doesn't have rational roots?

Comment: Please try to have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/why-can-all-quadratic-equations-be-solved-by-the-quadratic-formula/49243#49243

Comment: @DougM I know that the polynomial does not has rational roots. But still we can express it in the form $(ax + b \sqrt {c} ) (dx + e \sqrt {f})$, cant we?

Comment: @OlivierOloa The answer you linked is essentially a special quadratic case of the [AC method.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Yes, thanks for the new link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$5x^2-2x-10=5(x^2-\frac25x-2)=5\left((x-\frac15)^2-\frac{51}{25}\right)=
5\left((x-\frac15+\frac{\sqrt{51}}5)(x-\frac15-\frac{\sqrt{51}}5)\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$5x^2 - 2x - 10=0$$
$$5(x^2-\frac{2}{5}x-2)=0$$
$$5(x^2-\frac{2}{5}x-2+\frac{1}{25}-\frac{1}{25})=0$$
$$5(x^2-\frac{2}{5}x+\frac{1}{25})-5*2-5*\frac{1}{25}=0$$
$$5(x-\frac{1}{5})^2-\frac{51}{5}=0$$
$$(x-\frac{1}{5})^2-\frac{51}{25}=0$$
$$(x-\frac{1}{5})^2-(\frac{\sqrt51}{5})^2=0$$
now use the fact of
$$(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)$$
so
$$(x-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{\sqrt51}{5})(x-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{\sqrt51}{5})=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$5x^2-2x-10=5\left(x^2-\frac25x-2\right)=5\left(x^2-\frac25x+\frac1{25}-2-\frac1{25}\right)=5\left((x-\frac15)^2-\frac{51}{25}\right)=$$
$$=5\left(\left(x-\frac15\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{51}}{5}\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I edited

Answer (score 1):

I want to know whether I am using the wrong method or am I just not able to decide the next manipulation of the polynomial?

---

> $(1)$ $$\begin{align}5x^2 - 2x - 10\\
> = 4x^2 - 4x + 1 + x^2 + 2x - 11 \\
> = (2x - 1)^2 + x^2 + 2x - 11
> \end{align}$$
>
> $(2)$ $$\begin{align}5x^2 - 2x - 10\\
> = 9x^2 - 6x + 1 - 4x^2 + 4x - 11\\
> = (3x - 1)^2 - 4x^2 + 4x - 11
> \end{align}$$

---

To be able to factorise $(1)$,

By Factor Theorem,

For $$p_1(x)=x^2+2x-11$$ We must have $$p_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$

Clearly, $$p_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \neq 0$$

So, this method yields nothing useful.

In fact, for $$g_1(x)=5x^2-2x-10$$ We observe that $$g_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \neq 0$$

So, $k\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ or specifically $2x-1$ can't be a factor of $g_1(x)$

**Note:** A similar argument follows for $(2)$, which is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

Factor theorem provides the motivation for checking simple points and then hoping that if we get one root we get the other easily.

Let $f(x)=5x^2-2x-10$

Using Rational Root Thorem, we get that any rational root of the form $\dfrac{p}{q}$ can have $p \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5, \pm 10\}$ and $q \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5\}$

After checking through all the cases, we get $f(x)$ doesn't have any rational roots.

---

**Factorisation of quadratics in general**

Let $$5x^2-2x-10=(ax+b)(cx+d)=acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd$$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

Comparing like terms we get

$$ac=5\tag{1}$$

$$ad+bc=-2\tag{2}$$

$$bd=-10\tag{3}$$

**Note:** Although there appear less equations than variables. It may be noted that it is enough to find the ratio among $a,b,c,d$. For example, $$x^2-3x-2=(x-1)(x-2)=(2x-2)\left(\frac{x}{2}-1\right)$$

So, set $a=1$ and solve the $3$ equations to get the value of the remaining $3$ variables.

$\color{red}{\text{Warning: }}$ Since solving linear equations in many variable can be quite tedious, it is best if factorisation is done, in a similar manner, as answered (earlier) by other users.

Answer (score 0):

$$5x^2 - 2x - 10 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ x\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} -10 & -1+t\\ -1-t & 5\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ x\end{bmatrix}$$

We want to find a $t$ that makes the matrix above rank-$1$. Computing the determinant,

$$\det \begin{bmatrix} -10 & -1+t\\ -1-t & 5\end{bmatrix} = t^2 - 51$$

If $t = \sqrt{51}$, then the matrix is singular and, thus, rank-$1$. Computing the [eigendecomposition](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan%20decomp%20%7B%7B-10,-1%20%2B%20sqrt(51)%7D,%7B-1%20-%20sqrt(51),%205%7D%7D),

$$\begin{bmatrix} -10 & -1+\sqrt{51}\\ -1-\sqrt{51} & 5\end{bmatrix} = -5 \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{51}-1}{5}\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{51}+1}{5}\\ -1\end{bmatrix}^T = 5 \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{51}-1}{5}\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt{51}+1}{5}\\ 1\end{bmatrix}^T$$

Thus,

$$\begin{array}{rl} 5x^2 - 2x - 10 &= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ x\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} -10 & -1+\sqrt{51}\\ -1-\sqrt{51} & 5\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ x\end{bmatrix}\\ &= 5 \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ x\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{51}-1}{5}\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt{51}+1}{5}\\ 1\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ x\end{bmatrix}\\ &= 5 \left( x - \dfrac{1}{5} + \dfrac{\sqrt{51}}{5} \right) \left( x - \dfrac{1}{5} - \dfrac{\sqrt{51}}{5} \right)\\ &= \dfrac{1}{5} \left( 5 x - 1 + \sqrt{51} \right) \left( 5 x - 1 - \sqrt{51} \right)\end{array}$$