# $a$ algebraic number, $\exists$ integer $n>0$ such that $na$ algebraic integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

> If $a$ is an algebraic number, show that there exists a positive
>   integer $n$ such that $na$ is an algebraic integer.

I'm supposing that $a$ is algebraic over a field $F$, that is, there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ over $F$ such that $p(a) = 0$ . If we think about $F$ being $\mathbb{Q}$, then $a = p/q$. And if we think that $p(x) = x-a$, we have that $p(x) = x-p/q$ is our polynomial. But I don't know if it helps. I don't even know if we can suppose that $x-a$ is our polynomial

Comment: Hmm, usually "algebraic integer" means a complex number that is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. Besides, is your statement right? you can take $n=1$.

Comment: @Xam yes, I think I misunderstood the definition of algebraic integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(a)=0$ be monic, degree $n$. If the polynomial is not already a polynomial over the integers, it has a term whose coefficient is rational, with denominator $q$ when fully reduced. Suppose that's the coefficient of $x_k$.

Let $g(x)=q^nf(x/q)$. Note that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $g$ is a whole number, $g$ is monic, and $g(qa)=0$.

If $g$ still has some non-integer rational coefficients, repeat until you do have a polynomial whose coefficients are all integers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer#Definitions

Comment: if the polynomial is not already a polynomial over the integers, it has a term whose coefficient is rational, with denominator $q$. Suppose that's the coefficient of $x^k$. Then $g$ is a polynomial with $g(qa)=0$, and the coefficient of $x^k$ is an integer. Repeat until you have a coefficient whose coefficients are all integers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Recall from high-school the AC-method that transforms factoring any polynomial into one that is  $\,\rm\color{#c00}{monic}\,$ (lead coeff $=1)$ e.g. as follows:

$$\quad\ \ \begin{eqnarray}
f &\,=\,& \ \  9\ x^2-\ 80\ x\ -\,\ 9\\
\Rightarrow\ 9f &\,=\,& (9x)^2\! -80(9x)-81\\
         &\,=\,& \ \ \ \  \color{#c00}{X^2\!- 80\  X\ -\,\ 81},\,\ \ X\, =\, 9x\\
         &\,=\,&  \ \ \ \,(X-81)\ (X+\,1)\\
         &\,=\,& \ \ \ (9x-81)\,(9x+1)\\
\Rightarrow\  f\,=\, 9^{-1}(9f)  &\,=\,&   \ \ \ \ \  (x\ -\ 9)\,(9x+1)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

If we denote our factoring algorithm by $\,\cal F,\,$ then the above transformation is simply

$$\cal F f\,  = a^{-1}\cal F\, a\,f\quad\,$$

Thus we've transformed by $ $ *conjugation* $\,\ \cal F = a^{-1} \cal F\, a\ \,$ the problem of factoring non-monic polynomials into the simpler problem of factoring monic polynomials. 
This is sometimes called the **AC method**. It works for higher degree polynomials too. As above, we can reduce the problem of factoring a non-monic polynomial to that of factoring a monic polynomial by scaling by a  $ $ *power* of the lead coefficient $\rm\:a\:$ then changing variables: $\rm\ X = a\:x$

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\: a\:f(x)\:\! \,=\,\:\! a\:(a\:x^2 + b\:x + c)  &\,=\,&\rm\: X^2 + b\:X + \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\smash[t]{\overbrace{ac}^{\rm\qquad\ \ \ \ \ {\bf AC-method}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! =\, g(X),\ \ \ X = a\:x \\
\\
\rm\: a^{n-1}(a\:x^n\! + b\:x^{n-1}\!+\cdots+d\:x + c) &\,=\,&\rm\: X^n\! + b\:X^{n-1}\!+\cdots+a^{n-2}d\:X + a^{n-1}c
\end{eqnarray}$$ 
After factoring the monic $\rm\,g(X)\, =\, a^{n-1}f(x),\,$ we are guaranteed that the transformation reverses to yield a factorization of $\rm\:f,\ $ since $\rm\ a^{n-1}$ must divide into the factors of $\rm\ g\ $ by Gauss' Lemma, i.e. primes  $\,p\in\rm\mathbb Z\,$ remain prime in $\rm\,\mathbb Z[X],\,$ so $\rm\ p\ |\ g_1(x)\:g_2(x)\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,\rm\:p\:|\:g_1(x)\:$ or $\rm\:p\:|\:g_2(x).$

Clearly this resolves your problem (and more). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242) for further discussion.