# Proof that if $\sqrt {ab}$ is rational then $\sqrt {\frac{a}{b}}$ is also rational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I can reduce it using the fact that square root of a number is rational if it is a square number. 
Now it would be something like :
If $ab=k^2$ for some $k$ in $N$ then show that $\frac{a}{b}=m^2$ for some $m$ in $N$

Where $a$,$b$ belongs to $N$

$N$ is the set of natural numbers.

I have tried prime factorisation also 
But do not know how to proceed.

---

### CLAIM

---

If $a$,$b$ belongs to $N$ and if $\sqrt ab$ is integer then prove that $\sqrt \frac{max(a,b)}{min(a,b)}$   is also an integer.
Where $N$ is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: What are $a,b$?  If you just mean real numbers then it is false...try $a=\pi, b=\frac 1{\pi}$.

Comment: If you meant natural numbers then just note that $\frac ab=\frac {ab}{b^2}$.

Comment: Yes i mean natural number

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect that.  With that requirement, my hint applies.

Comment: @lulu i have tried like that i.e. say $ab=k^2$ then divide $b^2$ both sides you will get $\frac{a}{b}= \frac{k^2}{b^2}$ but then how do you prove that the RHS belongs to natural number ?

Comment: Nobody asked that it be a natural number.  That is clearly not always the case...if $a=1,b=4$ then $\sqrt {ab}=2$ but $\sqrt \frac ab=\frac 12$.

Comment: Note:  your edit still says nothing about what $a,b$ are.  That's absolutely critical to the question!  And, as ,my last comment shows, the way it is now written, the claim is false.

Comment: I guess if a is not 1 then it would belong to N

Comment: Please try a few examples before making claims like that.

Comment: Say 24×6 then 24/6 both are square numbers.

Comment: Please try many examples.  Really.  Also, as I have pointed out, as stated the claim is false.

Comment: @lulu thank you sir for your time.

Comment: You cannot prove something true if it is only sometimes true. Sure, $a=24$ and $b=6$ gives you two natural numbers, but we've already seen what happens when $a=1$ and $b=4$ and it shows that you have written a false claim. Please review carefully what it was you were asked to show. The details matter. The details matter very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $ $  Employ $\,b\sqrt{a/b} = \sqrt{ab}.\,$ This is a special case of a general method. Let's view it that way.

Observe that $\, \overbrace{bx^2 = a}^{\large\ \ x\ =\ \sqrt{a/b}}\!\!\!\!\overset{\large \times\ b}\iff\! \overbrace{(bx)^2 = ab}^{\large\,\ bx\ \ =\ \ \sqrt{ab}}\ $ for $\,b\neq 0$

We scaled the LHS  by $b$  to get $\,X^2 = ab,\ X := bx\,$ which is now *monic* (lead coeff $=1).\,$   This is a special case of the monicization method used in the [AC method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242) for factoring non-monic quadratics.

The same method also works for higher-degree polynomials (as I explain in the linked post), which leads to higher-degree generalizations of the above identity for square-roots.

Generally the method shows that any algebraic number can be written as $\,\alpha = \beta/n\,$ where $\,n\in\Bbb Z\,$ and $\,\beta\,$ is an algebraic *integer* (i.e. a root of a *monic* $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]),$ e.g. above $\,\sqrt{a/b} = \sqrt{ab}/b,\,$ where $\,\sqrt{ab}\,$ is a root of the monic $\,x^2\!-ab\,$ so is an algebraic *integer*.

In higher-degree cases such equations are generally less obvious, so it is worth being aware of the general viewpoint (even though it is a bit overkill for this particular case).

Answer (score 2):

This hint will help you not only prove something you want to, but also state more clearly what you meant.

If $a,\,b$ are rational with $b\ne 0$ then $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{b}$ is the ratio of two rationals, the denominator non-zero. Any such ratio is rational (proof is an exercise).

Comment: Please see my claim !

Comment: @MDesmond Yeah, about that: when you wrote `\sqrt ab`, which obtains $\sqrt ab$ (note $b$ is outside the square root), did you actually mean $\sqrt{ab}$? If so your MathJax needs curly braces, viz. `\sqrt{ab}`.

Answer (score 1):

An "easy" algebraic proof:

if (assuming that $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers) $\sqrt {ab}={\frac{x}{y}}$, then $ab$ is a perfect "square fraction" i.e. $ab=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$. then $a=\frac{x^2}{by^2}$, and $\sqrt \frac{a}{b} =  \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{b^2y^2}}=\frac{x}{by}=\frac{n}{m}$.

Comment: Please see my claim

Answer (score 1):

First, point out that your statement doesn’t hold for $a,b,k,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Take for example $(a,b) = (2,18)$. Then $k = \sqrt{ab} = 6 \in \mathbb{N}$, but $m = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{1}{3} \notin \mathbb{N}$.

But the following statement does hold:

> If $ab = k^2$ with $a,b,k \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\frac{a}{b} = m^2$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Q}$, where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers.

*Proof:* If $ab = k^2$, then $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ab}{b^2} = \frac{k^2}{b^2} = (\frac{k}{b})^2$, so $m = \frac{k}{b}$ is rational, as desired.

Comment: Did you notice that 18/2 is a square number of a natural number

Comment: Please see my claim !

Comment: Yes, but 2/18 is not, which is enough as a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim works if and only if $b$ is rational.

Note that

$\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}}=b$

If numerator is rational then denominator is rational too.

> Counterexample for the case when $b$ is irrational take
>   $a=2\sqrt{2}$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$

Here $\sqrt{ab}=2$ however $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Please see my claim