# What is the best way to factor $25x^2-121$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

What is the best way to factor $25x^2-121$ ?

The methods I have been taught doesn't work for this problem. Is there an another way to solve this problem? If so, how?

Comment: $(5x-11)(5x+11)$

Comment: Do you know about the phrase "difference of squares"?  What method are you attempting to use?

Comment: $(5x)^2-(11)^2 = (5x-11)(5x+11)$.

Comment: "The method I have been t[aught] doesn't work for this problem" Which method is it?

Comment: Hmm, trying to think of the best way to hint you toward discovering the difference of squares on your own....  Basically $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ and if we replaces $a^2$ with $25x^2=(5x)^2$ and $b^2 $ with $121=11^2$ we get $25x^2-121=(5x+11)(5x-11)$.  But I don't want to *tell* you that... I want you to discover that on your own.... But I'm not sure the best hints to give you.

Comment: @fleablood I just thought of an idea. Rewrite the equation as $25x^2 + 0x - 121$. Then use the standard method for factoring trinomials: find factors of $-121\times25$ that add to $0$ and all that.

Comment: To see where the "difference of two squares" formula comes from, just try multiplying out $(a+b)(a-b)$ and see what happens. It's incredibly useful.

Comment: Yeah... It's been a long time since I've had to think about how to teach "the standard method".  I'd like the OP to show us how s/he tried to factor using the "methods s/he's been taught".  I'm sure s/he's just making an arithmetic error.

Comment: To be honest, I was never taught how to factor these without using "difference of two squares," (might even be my first time introducing a $+0x$ into factoring to make it work?). so I feel you on that matter fleablood. It was by a mere stroke of inspiration I came up with that analogy. Not so nice in finding the general identity, but it works nice enough for specific cases like this one.

Comment: See [the AC method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242)

Answer (score 8):

**Hint / Nudge:**

It depends on what you mean by "best," but there is a special formula for factoring the difference of two perfect squares:

$$a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$$

In your case, notice:

$$25x^2 - 121 = (5x)^2 - (11)^2$$

From here, you can factor the expression accordingly.

---

**Similar Question:**

> Let's factor the following: $$9x^4 - 16$$

Notice:

$$9x^4 - 16 = (3x^2)^2 - (4)^2$$

This is the difference of two perfect squares! In our above formula, take $a = 3x^2, b = 4$ and we find

$$9x^4 - 16 = (3x^2 - 4)(3x^2 + 4)$$

Note, too, that if you let $3 = (\sqrt 3)^2$, we can factor the left one even more if you wanted. This task is an exercise left to the reader, though. ;)

*(And of course, generally, when you're expected to factor, often you want to avoid having square roots since that introduces various problems. But it's a nice exercise to show you it can be done.)*

---

**Alternate Method:**

If you want to use more "standard" methods of factoring... well, let's recall what we call "standard":

- We begin with a trinomial, $ax^2 + bx + c$.
- We find factors of $a \cdot c$ that add up to $b$. Let those factors be $p, q$ for sake of argument.
- Then $ax^2 + bx + c = (x + p/a)(x + q/a)$.
- Next if the fractions $p/a$ and $q/a$ have a denominator even after simplifying, you'll want to "move" that denominator next to $x$. For example, $(x + 2/5)$ turns into $(5x+2)$.

This is the method we're all familiar with. So suppose, for example, in our case, we're looking at $25x^2 - 121$ as given. We notice:

$$25x^2 - 121 = 25x^2 + 0x - 121$$

In this light we can factor this expression using the old method. (This exercise is left to the reader. :p)

Personally, the difference of squares method is faster and simpler, but this should work too.

Comment: Special case of the [AC method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242)

Answer (score 2):

The hard way:

We want to factor, *IF* it can be done, as

$25x^2 -121 = (ax + b)(cx + d) = acx^2 + (bc+ad)x + bd$ where

$ac = 25;  bd= -121; bc+ad= 0$.

*IF* this can be factored to $ac =25$ means $a,c$ can be factored as $1,25$ or $5,5$.

And $bd =121$ means $b,d$ can be factored to $\pm 1;\mp 121$ or $\pm 11, \mp 11$.

But we have $ad = -bc$  of the options, if $a=25$ then $b=1$ and we can't have $25d = -c$ as $c$ can't have anything to do with $5$.

The same issues occur if $b = 121$.

To get $ad = -bc$ it helps if $|a| = |c| = 5$ and $|b|=|d| = 11$.  Then everything is nicely balanced and should cancel out.

And indeed:  $(5x + 11)(5x - 11) = 5x\times 5x + 11\times 5x + 5x\times(-11) + 11\times(-11) = 5x^2 - 121$.

The easy way:

Remember the "difference of squares" rule:  $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.

So $25x^2 = (5x)^2$ and $121 = 11^2$ so $25x^2 -121 = (5x)^2 - (11)^2 = ((5x) + (11))((5x) - (11)) = (5x +11)(5x-11)$.

Comment: Note that in your general checks for how the values can be factored, you are assuming that the coefficients $a, b, c, d$ are integers, which doesn't have to be the case in general.  However, no such restriction was provided in the problem statement (although it is implicit based on the use of perfect square coefficients), so you may wish to make it clear you are making this explicit assumption.

Comment: That's what those emphasised *IF*s were for.