# How is this step acheived? $h(x)= 27x^6+26x^3-1 $

Tags: functions, roots, quadratics

Find all real roots of $h(x)$.

[image]

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YObZc.jpg)

I have solved the question by letting $u = x^3$ and then using the quadratic formula to solve $27u^2+26u-1 = 0$.

However I don't have a clue as to how they've achieved  $27x^3 -1x^3+1=0$ as one of the steps. I have highlighted the section in the image linked Solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: $(27u-1)(u+1) = 27 u^2 +26 u - 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo, it should read

$$ \begin{align}&27(x^3)^2 + 26 x^3 - 1\\ =\ &(27x^3-1)(x^3+1) \end{align}$$

**Remark** $ $ You could have inferred this from what follows, i.e. they reduce it to

$\,x^3 = 1/27\,$ and $\,x^3 = -1\,$ implying that it has factors $\,27x^3-1\,$ and $\,x^3+1$

Worth mention is that we can use the [AC method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242) to factor such polynomials, i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\: a\:f(x)\:\! \,=\,\:\! a\:(a\:x^2 + b\:x + c)  &\,=\,&\!\!\rm\: \color{#c00}{X^2} + b\:X + \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\overbrace{ac,}^{\rm\qquad\ \ \ \ \ {\bf\large\ \  AC-method}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \  X = a\:x \\
\end{eqnarray}$$ In our case $$ {\begin{eqnarray}
f \, &\,=\,& \ \ \,  27 x^2+\ 26\ x\,\ -\ \ 1\\
\Rightarrow\,\ 27f\, &\,=\,&\!\,\ (27x)^2\! +26(27x)-1\\
         &\,=\,& \ \ \   \color{#c00}{X^2}+\, 26\  X\,\ -\ 1,\,\ \ X\, =\, 27x\\
         &\,=\,&  \ \ \ \ (X+27)\ (X-1)\\
         &\,=\,& \  (27x+27)\,(27x-1)\\
\Rightarrow\ \  f\:=\: \color{#0a0}{27^{-1}}\,(27f)\,  &\,=\,&   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x+ 1)\ (27x-1)\\
\end{eqnarray}}$$